# ASP.NET Access denied error

Tags: asp.net

Access to the path "c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v1.1.4322\Temporary ASP.NET Files\hsbc9.0\699bfba7\9247b8b2" is denied.

Hi,

When i click on browse in iis I couldn't open my application,instead am getting the above mentioned error,Please help me on this.

Thanx in advance
Preeti.

Answer (score 2):

Try running `aspnet_regiis -ir` from Visual Studio Command Prompt. Or see [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/rchartier/archive/2006/01/05/434626.aspx).

Comment: When i run this command in command prompt am getting this error,can u tell me where to run this?
C:\Documents and Settings>aspnet_regiis -ir
'aspnet_regiis' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @Preeti Look for a shortcut called "Visual Studio 20xx Command Prompt" in your Start menu, launch it and then execute this command in that window.

Comment: Hi, My application is working with the help of this Solution: Grant ASP.NET Machine Account full access to ASP.NET temp folder

Answer (score 0):

these are temp files you can delete all the files in c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v1.1.4322\Temporary ASP.NET Files\

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting this from intellisense in the IDE before ever deploying, like I was, you can do one of the following:

1. Run Visual Studio as an administrator.
2. Give "Users" (or your
   own account) full control of
   C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\